# Interpolation to match dataset size

Tags: python, matlab, math, statistics, numerical-methods

If I have two datasets with different sizes for example:

```
x1 = [0,2,5,10,12,20,15,14] #length = 8
y1 = [0,0.3,0.6,1.1,1.3,2.1,1.6,1.5] #length = 8

x2 = [0,2,4,5,10,12,13,20,18,15,14] #length = 11
y2 = [0.3,0.4,0.5,0.7,1.1,1.3,1.4,2.2,1.6,1.9,1.8] #length = 11
```

How can I get the x1,y1 data to match the x2,y2 data size? So they both get length 11.

I have had a look at `scipy.interpolate` and its other functions. But I don't get correct numbers, or I am using wrong functions. If someone knows the correct function or a different method to solve this, then it would be great.

So the final lengths of x1,y1 would be 11.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use interp1

https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/interp1.html

x1i = interp1(1:8, x1, linspace(1,8,11), 'spline');

y1i = interp1(1:8, y1, linspace(1,8,11), 'spline');

Comment: Great, i seen this in matlab, but didnt know how to get it to work to get both x1,y1. Now i understand. Thanks!

Comment: I have a question, is there a method of this exact MATLAB function in other languages, the python `np.interp()` doesnt have the same result neither does the `scipy.interp1d`.